# Incomplete downloads reported as complete - Firefox - regular occurance

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, download

I am having a problem with Firefox where downloads are incomplete, but they are reported as complete.  This happens with multiple file types (exe's, zips, videos).  There is no circular arrow icon next to the download to restart it, which is what happens when firfox reports a download is incomplete.  I have to go back to the original source to restart the download.  This has been happening for the past 2 months.  Retrying the download eventually solves the problem.  Firefox has had an update during this time frame (installed).  I tried uninstalling/reinstalling Firefox.

Firefox 20.0.1
Windows XP SP3

Comment: Firefox 20 is sort of old.  Have you confirmed that problem exists in the current release version?

Comment: Is this only with downloads from some particular site? Are you using any kind of proxy?